# How can I compare a String with ArrayList full of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

I have in my main class this code:

```
 System.out.println("pls enter the id that you are looking for");
 String id = keyboard.nextLine();

 for(int k=0;k<elements.size();k++){

   elements.Hotell.get_Idset().equals(id);

 }
```

And I want to search for a id into my `ArrayList` that is full of objects.

First I read the id(`String`) from the keyboard and I want to compare with my `ArrayList` to find if this id exists.

Also the method `get_Idset()` belongs to Class `Hotell`, 
so I am getting an error:

> cannot find symbol variable Hotell

I did not find an answer.

My `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Object> elements = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: What do you expect with elements.Hotell? elements is an ArrayList, it doesn't have such a member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the following changes:

- Make `elements` list of `Hotell` and not `Object` instances, e.g.:
  `ArrayList<Hotell> elements = new ArrayList<Hotell>();`
- Iterate the list and use `get_Idset()` (assuming it returns a String) to get and compare the id

Below is the example:

```
ArrayList<Hotell> elements = new ArrayList<Hotell>(); //Your list
String id = keyboard.nextLine();
Optional<String> element = elements.stream()
        .filter(e -> e.get_Idset().equals(id))
        .findFirst();
if(element.isPresent()){
    System.out.println("Element found");
}else{
    System.out.println("Element not found");
}
```